# Why does it take 1000 reputation to view the vote count?

Tags: discussion, vote-count

I was reading an interesting post on another Stack Exchange site, and I hovered the mouse over the vote number and clicked it.  Then I realized that I have less than 1000 reputation on that community and I cannot view all the vote count.  Why is viewing the vote count that expensive?

Comment: resources, simply. Votes are saves as an aggregate in the DB. So getting the vote-break is another call. If everyone could do it, we'd lose speed.

Comment: Answer on the mother Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269354/why-are-users-with-less-than-1000-rep-unable-to-see-vote-counts and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/1007#1007

Comment: Quote: "Also: downvotes are still quite rare on Stack Overflow".  Ah, those halcyon years.

Comment: ["View Vote totals" without 1000 rep](http://stackapps.com/q/3082)

Comment: @HansPassant A much smaller percentage of posts were made back in the day which needed downvotes/removal.  Consequences of a successful website.

Comment: The original "resources" excuse sounds like such a Jeff-ism. I'm sure it's not really true today, if it ever was. (Jeff had an occasional habit of making up quick excuses and then stubbornly clinging to them). I'm sure the very capable developers, who have optimized the hell out of this software, could display the vote counts 100% of the time without a meaningful hit to performance, and that the site wouldn't suffer at all if the click-to-reveal feature were lowered to 1 rep today. It's 1000 rep because it's a nice checkpoint in your progress, and that's it.

Comment: @HansPassant Good thing, we can confirm this with site analytics 25K tools. In 2008 the ratio between up and downvotes was ~11 and increased steadily to ~21 in Feb 2011. Then the decline began with ~7 now.

Comment: There are other sites that hide up/down vote counts and/or fuzz the total vote, to discourage someone confirming the result of automated bot voting - or something like that. Is this rationale true for Stack Exchange as well?

Comment: I think @Nayuki might have the answer. Low rep hurdle for seeing the vote count would make it much easier for bots to probe the voting system and find ways to game it.

Comment: @ButtleButkus, That doesn't really make sense, since everyone can view vote counts with a userscript, see Bhargav Rao's comment. It's also available for everyone in the [timeline](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/318306/timeline), no userscript needed. So if a bot wants the vote counts, it can get them. (I believe this info is also accessible via the Stack Exchange API).

Comment: A more credible explanation than "resources" is "we just needed some crack to give out at the 1000 reputation level." I could swear I heard Jeff or one of his homies say that back in the day, but I'm probably misremembering.

Comment: **resources**??    in any social media thingy like this you simply store the total *and the two components also*, of course. look at it this way, no matter what paradigm of data storage (sql, nosql, whatever), if you don't do the calculation on the fly, you'd keep all three components.  (just in theory: if you're actually doing it on the fly each time, which would likely be a bit nuts, there's no difference doing all three) of course you keep a count of up and down ikes as well as the total (or just add the two components to get the total).  Obviously.

Comment: @JoeBlow, Sure, they could fix it to have all three available with reasonable performance (remember, this was built 8 years ago, and they probably _didn't_ want to spend time optimizing it back then). Is it worth the development time for SE to optimize it now ? Probably not.

Comment: hi @jonascz, nah like any of the zillions of systems like this out there of course it will have (essentially) the up and down component.  (it has nothing to do with "performance" or "optimizing", it's a line of code)

Comment: @JoeBlow, I can assure you that it's [more than just a line of code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/10/28/how-many-microsoft-employees-does-it-take-to-change-a-lightbulb/) :-)

Comment: lol funny article  :)

Comment: Also discussed in this main Meta question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77893/148833

Comment: I didn't know such feature exists. Now I am going to abuse it (by clicking everything I can click), thanks!

Comment: And, yea verily, they did spake to one another, saying "What shall the counting of the reputation be for viewing thine votes upon the questions and answer?" and the answer came "The counting of the reputation shall be 1000, for 1001 is too many. 1002 is right out..."

Comment: 1000 points really isn't that much, and what with SE point deflation the longer the site's up, it's less and less of a bar to hit. What's the practical pain in waiting?

Comment: @ruffin I think you argue from the wrong end. The question should rather be what the practical gain in waiting is. I guess the practical gain is close to zero or negative.

Comment: @Trilarion I'd also have thought awarding made-up status points (& hats!) would have a practical gain approaching zero, but SO has proven me wrong. Points and privileges are genuinely motivating. And **what good is it to see the vote count other than curiosity?** I may have thrown a vote to an okay answer that's +0 -1 rather than +5 -6, but shouldn't I just be voting on merit? That is, there's no serious practical gain giving the privilege at 0, 100, or 500 other than satisfying curiosity. [Rene's answer on efficiency](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318347/1028230) makes 1k make sense to me.

Comment: @ruffin I see the gain. It's gamification. But there is also a loss. Not having privileges is genuinely demotivating. Just in case I would be a guy who is motivated even without awarded made-up status points, could I maybe have the privileges right from the start (if only I credibly promise that I will contribute anyway - and if not I give them back)? I always wanted to write a user script that modifies the display of SO pages so that the rep of the people is not displayed anymore neither the medals and the score is translated to something like "rather bad", "okayish", "rather good".

Comment: @ruffin And what good is it to see the vote count other than curiosity? It's useful. It gives you insight into controversiality and popularity. See comments on Colin Pitrats answer here.

Comment: @Trilarion I'll stop after this, as it's a little tangent-y. 2¢: If downvoters would leave constructive feedback in comments, we'd have a better site. Downvoting without critique isn't useful. Answers that deserve downvotes without explanation (except on meta) deserve [*not an answer* flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag) instead. Vote on a Q/A's merit, not what votes came before you. Vote counts are simply interesting; pick a point threshold out of a hat to assign the privilege that also keeps the servers happy. 1k works well nuff.

Comment: @Patrice You say this is a speed issue? How? The current functionality shows the aggregate number of up and down votes (upvotes - downvotes) I want to see upvotes, downvotes.

Comment: @MatthewSontum 1 call for "totalscore" and 2 calls for "upvotes" then "downvotes". They save the aggregate, which is why querying for both numbers separately impacts performance.

Comment: @Patrice It's still one call, you are just returning two columns: SELECT upvotes, downvotes from ___, instead of SELECT score from ___. Whatever mechanism they use to maintain score would be modified to maintain upvotes, downvotes instead.

Comment: @MatthewSontum ok, I was overly simplifying to not make it more complicated that it has to be. The table isn't compiled this way, which makes retrieving the whole count slower, as the "upvotes" and "downvotes" fields aren't maintained.   They DO need to update and maintain up and downvotes separately for it to work, which they don't. Changing this on ALL the posts would be..... quite an update to be fair.

Comment: @Patrice Certainly you wouldn't want to make this modification during a period of high volume usage. But since you were already willing to have one denormalized column to track score, it would not be a significant change to the data model to replace score with two denormalized columns. My suggestion would be to leave score in for now, add the two new columns, populate them, flip the code to using the new columns, then remove the original score column. You'll want to do this anyway, even if you don't give out the ability to lower rep people. Since they can already run a script.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I'm rephrasing the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269356/158100) from [Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded) and the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1007/158100) from [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)

The 1000 reputation threshold is a way to limit the use of a somewhat expensive operation, by allowing only a smaller subset of users to perform it, and only on request at that.

The operation is expensive because the breakdown of up- and down votes isn't stored in the posts table. If we assume the [SEDE Database schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) is somewhat similar we see that the posts table only holds the de-normalized attribute `score`. To get the breakdown of up and down votes for a question you would need to run something like [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/445786):

```
select sum(case
           when votetypeid = 2 then 1  -- UPMOD
           else 0
           end ) as up
     , sum(case
           when votetypeid = 3 then 1 -- DOWNMOD
           else 0
           end ) as down
from votes 
where postid = 477816
```

for each post that gets rendered.

Do notice that it isn't impossible for users without the privilege to obtain the vote break down. This [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/557/votecounts-bookmarklet-to-display-up-down-votes-even-for-rep-less-than-1000) from [sztupy](https://stackapps.com/users/1265/sztupy) offers the feature to anyone who installed that script.

Comment: That would be a reason to not simply load it for every page request but I still don't see the reason for this to be a reputation based privilege. The expense is obviously not intolerable as the facility exists, and the suggested workarounds such as viewing the question timeline will be even more expensive.

Comment: @MartinSmith But the timeline is not instantly accessible from the UI except for mods. Somewhere the decision was made to only unlock the vote count split at 1000 rep. I think nobody finds it worth the time to revisit that decision, create a fix that overcomes  any existing performance penalty, or reveal other reasons why this feature is privileged based.

Comment: @rene the same problem as everywhere: It doesn't affect ad revenue, so nobody cares.

Comment: @JanDvorak More like: the same problem as everywhere: there are only so many hours in the day, so not every minor nuisance can be looked at for hours.

Comment: hey @rene - it seems a bit bizarre you don't also just store the two components.  are you speaking as *someone who made this system* or are you just saying this is what you think

Comment: @JoeBlow this is what I think. I have re-read my answer but I can't pin-point exactly where I create the illusion that I made the system. If you can edit the answer to get rid of that would help me lot. My non-native English capabilities might be at play here.

Comment: @JoeBlow score is needed basically all the time, which makes it worth storing denormalized. Apparently up and down counts aren't important enough to justify storing two more fields per post and keep them in sync with the truth in the votes table. And really... that's sensible enough.

Comment: What would be so bad about storing one more field per post? Answer: Nothing really.

Comment: Fun fact: that userscript got me a StackOverflow T-shirt

Comment: "this is what I think" .. oh ok.  no, it's almost inconceivable that anyone so inexperienced would have been on the system all these years that they wouldn't think to save the two components.  Note too that *if* it was actually adding in realtime when you click the components button, it would take forever.

Comment: hi @rene no you did not in any way imply you work at SO - I was just asking.  My English is crap also  :)  cheers buddy !!

Comment: hi @hobbs, nah nobody on Earth would not realise you store the two components of a sum like that.  there are more social media engineers out there than anything, its' a well-worn field

Comment: @Trilarion A post could have a cached vote count which is allowed to go stale (a flag indicates when it is valid).  Whenever the question is voted on, the flag is flipped to indicate that the count is no longer valid.  When the vote count needs to be displayed, and is invalid, then it is recalculated and marked valid. As an optimization, when the display is being done for the sake of the user who altered the vote count, the local javascript logic in the browser can avoid recalculating the count; it can just sneakily adjust the value displayed according to the voting action which the user took.

Comment: My guess is that performance or implementation difficulty is not really the problem here. The answer of SergeyA about it just being a privilege describes the issue more clearly.

Comment: @rene You are saying that it is easier to read from the denormalized value score. Why not just retain two denormalized values, upvotes and downvotes?

Answer (score 25):

Short answer - it is a badge.

### Long answer

Stack Overflow needs to keep revenue coming. To keep revenue coming, it needs the users to keep coming. To keep users coming, it needs to lure them. How do you lure askers? By promising them answers. How do you lure answer providers? By promising them some form of compensation. How can Stack Overflow compensate? By giving the sense of accomplishment, by giving a badge. And if it can add a bit of substance to the badge - the badge becomes a more desired prize. By slowly giving those perks with every new milestone of rep achieved, SO keeps answer providers filled with self-importance (I can see vote counts!, and you, sir, can not!), so that they keep providing answers.

Or, in another words, since SO can't compensate you for the answer with money, it compensates you with the privilege.

Comment: I like this answer !

Comment: I always wondered if this really works like that? I never gave much about the badges but I liked helping. I actually would have contributed totally for free without any compensation. So now say that I will only continue contributing if SO grants this privilege to everyone. According to the logic presented in this answer, this is actually the only way of changing the rules of the game. So, I demand no payment as payment!! Only thing left to do: convince majority of SO user of the wisdom of that. :)

Comment: I neither like nor dislike [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318306/why-does-it-take-1000-reputation-to-view-the-vote-count/318470#comment318471_318470).

Comment: Excellent answer. I was confused by the previous one, that implied it was a performance issue when clearly it is not. Then I guess my main question is why this particular feature is 1000, not 100 or something. Most of the other useful badges are given out pretty early on.

Comment: Not a badge, a privilege.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's part of Stack Exchange principle to earn some privileges with participation to the site. The breakdown is a small privilege that you earn at a given point. It's not very useful but it's nice to have it and you're happy to have it once you reach 1k.

In fact, I would even say that if you didn't have to earn it, you wouldn't find it that nice a feature !

The load on the DB may be an historical justification. But as said in the comments, it would be easy to make the feature more scalable if this was needed or a priority. But in the end, what matters to evaluate a post is the score, not the breakdown.

If you had all features unlocked when creating your account on stackoverflow, you wouldn't have the incitation of the next privilege you track to increase your reputation. For some users it doesn't count, for some it does. In the end, I think it adds to the global motivation of the community (as badges, reputation and all the other metrics that have nothing to do with asking & answering questions)

Comment: It's not only a privilege (like more comfortable chairs) but also a useful information making the use of the site more efficient. There is a case for displaying it earlier. Surely we could have other nice privileges instead like bigger avatars, ... whatever.

Comment: I don't really see how it makes the usage of the site more efficient ...

Comment: It does. 4 upvotes, no downvote mean that this particular contribution is rather less popular but unanimously found to be good. 10 upvotes and 6 downvotes mean that this particular contribution is very visible but also highly controversial. Yet the sum is the same in both cases. Having the two dimensions separated allows you to infer better on controversity and popularity. That's useful and makes you use SO more efficiently.

Comment: Fair enough (even though for your own question, the reputation earned / loss gives you a good hint), but that's a rather 'advanced' tool. Therefore keeping it for experienced users make sense. Now the initial remark about various Stack Exchange sites is valid: a user that knows the concept of one site knows the concept of others so he could benefit from the feature. But that's also an incentive to contribute more to this community.

Comment: I don't think it is an 'advanced' tool. You could see it as such, but it is just the sum of all positive votes and the sum of all negative votes, separately. If this is an advanced feature, what about search for example?

Comment: It's not complex to understand or implement but it doesn't mean it's simple to use effectively.

Comment: I find it very simple to use effectively although I also find that I do not need to use it all the times, so it's not that important but that could be said of many other things too. Also, in general, I think that the feature is not overly difficult to use effectively. It just gives you a more detailed view into what people really thought about a contribution and with a bit of experience using it everyone can estimate with good accuracy what different directions in the 2dimensional up/downvote space mean.

Comment: "It's not a design flaw, it's a fringe benefit." -1, not directed at you (this is a good writeup), but at SE. Oh well.

Answer (score 7):

I think 1000 reputation is too high a level for this, and that anyone that can downvote (125 reputation) should be able to see the vote counts.

Comment: I think around 500 should be fair. 125 is easily reached. Also, at such low rep, the user might be inclined to vote after seeing + and -.

Comment: @EvanCarslake: I agree, 1000 seems high for what appears to be a fairly insignificant power. When first starting out, 1k is a milestone. Think about it: at 2k rep, you can edit posts directly, and at 3k rep you can start voting to close questions. At 1k... you can see how  a number is summed. It *feels* underwhelming, even though (as other answers have explained) there's a technical reason for this. I'm not arguing to actually have this number changed, but I did want to give my $0.02

Comment: Everyone, can we all agree on 367 as a good compromise?

Comment: I agree that it should be lower. I thought 100 at first, but perhaps that is too low considering some of the automatic 100 bonuses given out. Maybe ... 200? 500? 1000 is definitely too high on some of the peripheral stack exchange sites. Maybe it could vary by site?

Comment: @EvanCarslake Certainly people would be inclined to vote based on that information, but they already vote based on the total score. I've seen a number of well-thought out, completely factually accurate answers nosedive after they went below -5. People just figure that the other people know well enough that they'll follow the pack. I try to upvote these answers when I see them, even when they are not the top, best answer, but I can only do so much.

Comment: 750!!!!!!! PLEASE!